# What theme element controls the TextField widget focused color

Tags: flutter

I have an app that is using ThemeData.dark().  When I tap on a text field, the label and text field turn a shade of green that I'd like to change.

[image]

What aspect of the theme do I have to change to get a different color?

Edit: I implemented the answer and still wasn't getting the label to be blue.  So I started working backward in my code, removing various elements of the TextField and found that the color wasn't being carried forward if there was a labelStyle applied.  This doesn't work:

```
return Container(
  child: TextField(
    controller: widget.textFieldController,
    inputFormatters: [
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
      ThousandsFormatter(
        allowFraction: true,
      ),
    ],
    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
      signed: false,
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: widget.labelText,
      hintText: widget.hintText,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

If I remove the labelStyle, the it works fine:

```
return Container(
  child: TextField(
    controller: widget.textFieldController,
    inputFormatters: [
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
      ThousandsFormatter(
        allowFraction: true,
      ),
    ],
    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
      signed: false,
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: widget.labelText,
      hintText: widget.hintText,
    ),
  ),
);
```

I do want to be able to apply the labelStyle so that I can change the fontSize and fontWeight.  Is this a bug in Flutter, or is there something else that I'm missing.

Edit: For the sake of simplicity, I created a new project with just one TextField on it and nothing else.  Just to eliminate any other possible causes.  I followed the instructions in the proposed answer and the label is still blue when the field does not have focus.

[image: Text Field Without Focus]
[image]

What I need to do is get it so that the label of the field without focus is the same default grey color as the underline.

This is the code that I implemented.  I don't think that I missed anything.

```
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    buttonColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade600,
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          style: BorderStyle.solid,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.deepPurple.shade600,
    ),
  ),

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
    // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'First Name',
        labelStyle:
            Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 16):

You will have to define your custom theme in which you have to do `ThemeData` `brightness` to `dark`.

If you will see the `ThemeData` class you will find out that it does nothing but only sets `brightness` to `dark` for `ThemeData.dark()`.

The properties that you are looking for is `border` and `labelStyle` inside the `InputDecorationTheme`. There are three properties for `border` namely `focusedBorder` when your `TextInput` is focused, `enabledBorder` when your `TextInput` is `enabled` in the form you are showing and `border` when you just want to set the default border.

The way you can do this is like this:

```
ThemeData data = ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
               style: BorderStyle.solid, 
               color: Colors.blue
          ),
        )
      )
    );
```

There is another `InputBorder` attribute called `OutlineInputBorder`, which usually is used when you want to define all the borders for the `TextInput`.

**EDIT:**

In `TextField` Widget there is a method called `_getEffectiveDecoration()`, which is responsible for setting the decoration for the `TextField`.

Here is a snippet of that method:

```
final InputDecoration effectiveDecoration = (widget.decoration ?? const InputDecoration())
      .applyDefaults(themeData.inputDecorationTheme)
      .copyWith(
        enabled: widget.enabled,
        hintMaxLines: widget.decoration?.hintMaxLines ?? widget.maxLines,
      );
```

In the above snippet it can be clearly seen that firstly the decoration that you provide for your `TextField` is set and then the defaults are applied which are taken from your `Theme`. What `applyDefaults` does is that, that it checks whether a particular property is already applied to the `TextField` or not, if yes, then that property will override the default property, if no, then it will apply the default styling for that property provided by the `Theme`.

So in your case, what you want is that, that you want to apply a combination of both that is applied in theme and that you have passed.

For that you will have to write your widget like this:

```
return Container(
  child: TextField(
    controller: widget.textFieldController,
    inputFormatters: [
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
      ThousandsFormatter(
        allowFraction: true,
      ),
    ],
    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
      signed: false,
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: widget.labelText,
      hintText: widget.hintText,
      labelStyle: Theme.of(context)
        .inputDecorationTheme
        .labelStyle
        .copyWith(
          fontSize: 15,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        ),
      ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: That did change the underline color to blue.  What is responsible for changing the label color that appears when the keyboard is open?  That is still showing up as green.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Scott, I have updated my answer to reflect that, actually its `labelStyle` that will do the job for you.

Comment: I wasn't getting the label to change color with the code.  I found that the issue was that I was using labelStyle.  I've updated my original post to indicate my findings.

Comment: Hi Scott, I have updated my answer likewise, hope this helps solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  The only issue that I am having is, I only want the label to turn blue when the TextField has focus and the keyboard is open.  Basically, I don't like the green color that seems to be the default for the dark theme.  So in all instances of where it turns green when the keyboard is open (underline and label), I'd like for it to turn blue instead.

Comment: Hey Scott, that's what I have addressed in the edited version of the answer, in order to do that you will have to use `Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,)` in `labelStyle` of the `InputDecoration`

Comment: I've updated the original post.  I implemented the code from the answer and am still seeing a blue label on non-focused fields.

Comment: I have the same issue as @ScottKilbourn - using labelStyle will change the label ALWAYS, but we don't want it changed always, ONLY when it is focused. I've searched extensively for this and have not found a solution either. Has anyone accomplished this?