# Flutter focused text field color

Tags: flutter, dart

By default in flutter focused color of text field is primary, I want to set another color (accent color)

There was similar questions in stackoverflow, here is one accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416619/6447123

Here we have two problem , (I choose Colors.red as focused color)

#### 1. `UnderlineInputBorder` will applied to all text field including non-UnderlineInputBorder like `OutlineInputBorder`

```dart
focusedborder: UnderlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    style: BorderStyle.solid, 
    color: Colors.red
  ),
)
```

#### 2. TextStyle applied in unfocused mode too

```dart
labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
```

### Default behavior

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Applied theme

[image]
[image]
[image]

### what I you want to achieve?

I want to change globally default behavior of flutter, by default it set `primaryColor` as focused color for text fields, I want to set `accentColor` as focused color for text fields

Comment: if you want to apply theme saperately to widgets use Theme Widget as a parent and pass it a custom data

Comment: No, I don't want to set separately, I want to globally set color of focused input to accent color

Comment: what do you want to achieve? change the question accordingly

Comment: I edited question